# VS2008 Linking to wrong boost libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have a legacy VS 2008 project for which I'm upgrading the boost version. However, when linking VS complains that it can't find a version of boost that it's not supposed to link to:

`cannot open file 'libboost_signals-vc90-mt-s-1_51.lib'`

I've defined $BOOST_ROOT to the path of boost v1_56 and use this to find headers and libraries so I have no idea why VS is looking for boost 1_51

I have gone through the settings (Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories) for include and library paths to see if there was anything hard coded to look for v1_51  but found nothing.

Any ideas why VS is looking for 1.51 when I have pointed at 1_56?

Thanks in adv.!

Comment: Look in VS Linker Input settings, May be your project is looking for libboost_signals-vc90-mt-s-1_51.lib. Also check additional dependencies

Comment: Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories only specifies the path where header/library files should be searched. Linker Input settings specify what libraries program should search for.

Comment: Thanks @user1, you correctly pointed out that my additional dependencies were incorrect. works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am eligible for points here!

Look in VS Linker Input settings, May be your project is looking for libboost_signals-vc90-mt-s-1_51.lib. Also check additional dependencies.

Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories only specifies the path where header/library files should be searched. Linker Input settings specify what libraries program should search for.